# Table Lock History

Tags: sql-server-2000, locks

Is there a way to know the lock history for a table?

In example, a list with all the locks that occurred on a table between 8:00 and 9:00.

Looking for answer that works on SQL Server 2000

Comment: No. You would need to set up a SQL Profiler Trace in advance to record the lock events if you needed them. (Likely to be quite a heavy weight trace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get current locks (eg syslocks). There is no lock history kept.

You'd have to run a SQL Profiler trace but it will generate a lot of data. Or poll syslocks periodically and store info in logging table.